# Como ativar todos os hosts virtuais em um container Docker

Tags: docker

Considerando os arquivos abaixo, como posso no build ativar todos os virtuais hosts (presentes no volume: ./Apache/)?

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: myapp
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../Desenvolvimento Web/:/var/www
      - ./Apache/:/etc/apache2/sites-available/
    working_dir: /var/www
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
    bzip2 curl git less mysql-client sudo unzip zip \
    libbz2-dev libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng12-dev libzip-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install bz2 && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd \
        --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \
        --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd && \
    docker-php-ext-install iconv && \
    docker-php-ext-install opcache && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip && \
    a2enmod rewrite && \
    service apache2 restart

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer \
    | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Answer (score 0):

Com base no seu docker-compose, web enxerga sua instância mysql pelo nome "mysql".

OBS:

A sua definição de:

```
ports:
    - 3306:3306
```

no mysql, só é útil para você do host acessar o mysql, seja com o workbench ou outra ferramenta, não está relacionada o seu container web.

Comment: Compreendi, mas no meu caso, tenho localmente no diretório: ./Apache/ os arquivos referentes aos hosts virtuais que estão sendo montados no container em: /etc/apache2/sites-available/, o que quero é durante o build registrar estes hosts virtuais, para evitar ter que entrar no container e executar um a2ensite...

Comment: Registrar seus hosts virtuais é uma operação exclusiva do apache, o docker só precisa expor sua porta 80 e 443, enquanto um dns deve direcionar a requisição para o seu host que possui o container.

Comment: Estou ciente. Mas por meio do Docker file é possível rodar "instruções" dentro do container, logo, acredito ser possível utilizar este recurso para ativar os hosts virtuais já existentes no volume compartilhado. É isso que quero fazer inicialmente, já as futuras entradas eu mesmo registrarei.

Comment: Se é algo a ser executado no apache, deve estar no dockerfile ou em um script sh executado ou no dockerfile, ou no run da aplicação